# Does Google index text in images for search

Tags: google-search, google-sites, google-image-search

I need to avoid finding files in a Google Site search, so I named them in a way that they wouldn't come up when looking for information on the site.

However, I noticed that image files, that contain some text started coming up when searching for words that exist in the text. Is it possible that search indexes the text in images or am I looking at something else?

If it does index text in images, is there any way I can avoid this or disable it altogether?

Thanks

Comment: You should use a robots.txt file, this can stop search engines from indexing specific files.

Comment: this question might explain why that is happening and confirms the text isn't directly read from images http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84508/how-to-inform-a-search-engine-about-the-text-in-an-image/

Answer (score 0):

Google can indeed read text that is within an image file. They have a patent for the technology, and I have seen it on occasion myself in image results.